# Como usar junit para testar jax rs no wildfly

Tags: wildfly, junit, jax-rs, jta

Criei o seguinte teste para validar o cadastro porém ao invés de retornar 201 com o recurso criado está gerando esse erro genérico. Minha DAO está funcionando isoladamente de forma normal (Criei um endereço de listagem usando a mesma) Teriam alguma pista do que poderia ser?

```
@Test
public void testAdicionaEspecie() {

    Especie especie = new Especie();
    especie.setDescricao("Especie Test");
    Entity<Especie> entity = Entity.entity(especie, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    System.out.println(entity);
    Response response = targetVetweb.path("prontuario/especies")
            .request()
            .post(entity);
    String locNovaEspecie = response.getHeaderString("Location");
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 201);
    assertTrue(!locNovaEspecie.isEmpty());

}
@Path("especies")
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postEspecie(Especie especie) {
    especieService.add(especie);
    return Response.created(URI.create(uriResource.toString() + "/especies/" + especie.getEspecieId())).build();
}
@Override
public void add(Especie especie) {
    animalDAO.salvarEspecie(especie);
}
```

Estou usando WildFly 10. Descobri na depuração que está falhando com TransactionRequiredException nas classes de teste. Inseri o datasource na configuração do WildFly e o meu arquivo de configuração do ORM contém:

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/vetwebds</jta-data-source>
```

Ou seja imagino estar usando jta para gerenciar transações, como faço para que o junit reconheça essa configuração e teste o meu cadastro? Já tentei usar a anotação Transactional no teste mas sem sucesso

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa que a sua classe esteja executando dentro do Servidor de Aplicação.

Você pode usar o Arquillian para subir um Container durante os testes ou pode criar um projeto à parte para realizar requisições HTTP usando o RestEasy por exemplo para testar o comportamento desejado (isso seria um teste de integração através da API exposta pelo seu serviço).

Ao configurar um pipeline de CI você pode, por exemplo, provisionar o ambiente, compilar seu projeto, fazer o deploy e depois executar os testes no segundo projeto para testes de integração.